# Border in the jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the image, below carousel, there is a line in between the jumbotron.
How to draw that line?

[image: carousel]

I used carousel for the brown color part.
The next part followed by carousel, is a jumbotron.
In jumbotron (from take picture part), there is a black color line in between.

I have tried many times to get that line, but I couldn't. Here is the bit of code which I have tried.

http://jsbin.com/wequkikapo/edit?output

Please fix my problem.

Comment: Hi Welcome to stackoverflow. SO users "do not write your code for you". How SO works? simple, ask a question, provide problem detail, explain what you have tried so far, where are you stuck, and we will help you. Looking for more detail, please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: First post, eh? Please try something on your own... We don't write codes for you

Comment: I have edited the question. Please look at it. If any edit is required, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a div like this wherever you need that horizontal short line:

```
<div style="width:120px; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; margin:20px auto;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have got that horizontal line. My question is about the vertical line which is acting as separation ( in the div after carousel).

Comment: Just add a border to the side of one of the divs.